# how to get profile pic of a user as it appears in new Timeline profile?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-profile

is there any way to get profile pic of a user 
as it appears into **timeline profile**(the one shown into `135px*135px` box)?

Comment: Why don't you just get the full size image and scale it down?  What language are you using?

Comment: i am using php but i want it to be exactly as it appears into users timeline.

Answer (score 2):

You can just take the result from `/user/picture` API call, which will be something like `https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/275322_662949469_2141062370_q.jpg` and replace the `_q` for `_n`, so it will be:

https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/275322_662949469_2141062370_n.jpg

Actually it's not 135x135, but that's the one facebook uses on timeline. In my case it's scaled down by 136x125 inside a 125x125 `div` with `overflow: hidden`, so everything more than 125x125 is hidden. You can take a look using DOM Inspector or Firebug

Comment: there is no need to replace _q for _n you can get it directly from `user/picture?type=large` and that's not i am asking about what i am asking is how to get exactly the way it is shown in the timeline.

Comment: +1 for the `?type=large`, but I answered your question too! If you use the DOM Inspector you'll notice that picture as being the large one, inside a 4px white border container, centered through javascript, exactly the same way I did on this site: http://www.meutunaosabeoqueaconteceu.com.br/ (on the posts section)